# force socket to timeout in python

Tags: multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

I'm using a socket to listen on a port in a while loop, with a 5 second timeout set by `socket.settimeout()`. But I have another method, which set's the listening port, and when called with a new port, i wanna force the socket to timeout so that I can reinitialise the socket and set the appropriate port inside the while loop. Is there a way to do that?

The socket is inside a subclass of `threading.Thread`

PS. Since this is my second day with Python, any other suggestions regarding any part would be most welcome. Thank you

## EDIT:

I almost forgot. I want to reinitialise the socket when the `setoutboundport` method is called.

## EDIT2

Man the whole code is messed up. I reexamined everything and it's really wrong for what I wanna achieve. Just focus on the main question. Timing out the socket.

```
import threading
import socket
import ResponseSender
import sys
import traceback

def __init__(self, inboundport, outboundip, outboundport, ttl=60):
    super(Relay, self).__init__()
    self.inboundport = inboundport
    self.outboundip = outboundip
    self.outboundport = outboundport
    self.ttl = ttl
    self.serverOn = True
    self.firstpacket = True
    self.sibling = None
    self.newoutboundport = 0
    self.listener = None
# ENDOF: __init__

def stop(self):
    self.serverOn = False
# ENDOF: stop

def setsiblingrelay(self, relay):
    self.sibling = relay
# ENDOF: setsiblingrelay

def setoutboundport(self, port):
    self.newoutboundport = port
# ENDOF: setoutboundport

def run(self):
    s = None
    try:
        while self.serverOn:
            if not s:
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

            if self.outboundport != self.newoutboundport:
                try:
                    s.close()
                except:
                    pass
                s.settimeout(4)
                s.bind(('', self.inboundport))
                print("Relay started :{0} => {1}:{2}".format(self.inboundport, self.outboundip, self.outboundport))

            print("---------------------------------------- LISTENING FOR INCOMING PACKETS")
            data, address = s.recvfrom(32768)
            print("Received {0} from {1}:{2} => sending to {3}:{4}"
                  .format(data, address[0], address[1], self.outboundip, self.outboundport))
            ResponseSender.sendresponse(address[0], address[1], data)
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
    except:
        print("Error: {0}".format(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())))
# ENDOF: run
```

Comment: I think it woud be easier to help if you show your code

Comment: @almanegra At first I didn't want to, because it's not complete, and there are variables that could seem irrelevant to you and cause confusion. But since you're right, I did :-)